# An easy way to calc PI with powers of 2 and square roots

Tags: computational-complexity, pi

I don't know if this algorithm is know, but I think it's an easy way to calc $\pi$ more quickly than others. The reason of this, it's because when I search for computing algorithms, I only find stochastic methods, or difficult methods to implement, or methods that consume too much time. Let me explain this simple method.

We know the exact value of $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$, it's $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

But, what's the value of $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^n})$ with $n\gt2$? We can use the middle angle formules: $\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}}$ and $\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)}{2}}= \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\alpha)}}{2}}$. We are going to use the sine formule only.

For $\frac{\pi}{8}$ we have:
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})= \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}}= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$$

For $\frac{\pi}{16}$ we have:
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{16})= ...= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$

For $\frac{\pi}{32}$ we have:
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{32})= ...= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$$

You can continue if you want, and you are going to obtain a collection of nested roots in function of the power of 2. We can conclude that:

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})= ...= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2... (n-2)_{nested roots}}}}}$$

We are using now the limit of the function $f(x) = \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ when x goes to 0.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

If we substitute $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})$ in the equation before, changing $x$ for $\frac{\pi}{2^n}$, and $x \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$, we obtain:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})}{\frac{\pi}{2^n}} = 1$$

Where we can conclude that

$$\pi= \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2... (n-2)_{nested roots}}}}}$$

A simple calculation with n = 14, it give to us 8 exact decimals:

$$\frac{16384 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}{2} =3.1415926...$$

I hope you understand it.

Comment: Computing many square roots is probably expensive enough to be a disadvantage of this method.

Comment: That's cute! I don't see a question though. What do you want from us?

Comment: Ou... nothing. I only want to post it, if it can be usefull.

Comment: This is a [variant](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07713.pdf) of an old formula due to Viete (around $1590$).

Comment: Yes @lulu, I didn't know it. I'm reading the paper, and Viete uses the same formula. I think this paper is better way. I don't know how computational methods doesn't use this formula actually. Thanks!.

Comment: $\pi -2^n\sin (\pi / 2^n)>\pi^34^{-n}/6$ for $n\ge 2$. This is not so great, especially when you have to do $n$ square-root calculations.... $\pi=8\arctan (1/3)+4\arctan (1/7)$ and $\arctan x= x(1-x^2/3+x^4/5-x^6/7-x^8/9+ ...)$ when $|x|<1$.

Comment: Should stress:  my comment was in no way intended to take away the joy of discovery.  It's a great formula...I just thought you might want to read some discussion of other aspects of it.

Comment: @lulu. I "discovered" the formula in the Q when I was in high school and was delighted even though I could see it was computationally tedious (i.e. inefficient).